# merge emgu and emgucv tags

Tags: support, retag-request

I believe [emgu](/questions/tagged/emgu) and [emgucv](/questions/tagged/emgucv) tags should be merged; a user supplied a tag wiki and description for both tags earlier, and [submitted the second one as a duplicate of the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/105964).

We might as well merge [emgu](/questions/tagged/emgu) into [emgucv](/questions/tagged/emgucv), because the "cv" variant has more questions and is the more specific name.